# Configuring Modbus Slave auto increment

Tags: modbus, slave

can I increase or decrease the auto-increment value and time from `modbus slave?` By default, the value incremented is `1` and time is `1 seconds`.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some additional details - i.e. what software are you using? (your question appears to relate to a specific application).

Comment: @Brits I am using `modbus slave` for it

Comment: ```modbus slave``` could refer to any slave using the modbus protocol (hence my confusion); but if I understand correctly you are using the [Modbus Slave](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_slave.html) application? In that application I believe the increment is fixed (been a while since I took a look at it). However as it can link to Excel it should be relatively simple to use VBA to achieve what you are looking for.